# Determine files of a specific type in a folder without using loop

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to use the FileSystemObject in VBA to determine the number of files of a specific type, such as .PDF, in a folder without using a loop such as

```
For Each file In folder.Files
    'Check file type and count
Next
```

Comment: Even if there's a library to do it, it can't neglect looking at each and every file anyways.  I don't think there's a faster way to do it.

Comment: What's wrong with the loop? If it's something you do often, stick it in a user-defined function.

Comment: Thank you bdares and Jean-Francois for helpful comments. So a loop seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without the FSO dependency while also negating the need to examine the file extension manually;

```
dim file as String, countOf As Long
file = Dir$("c:\xxxxxx\*.pdf")
Do until file = ""
    countOf = (countOf + 1)
    file = Dir$()
Loop

MsgBox countOf
```

Comment: That is an interesting approach Alex. But you are still using a loop to count the files, although you avoid the files that don't match the criteria.

Comment: This seems to be the best approach, as it is also faster than using the FileSystemObject.

Answer (score 0):

For Excel, you need to use a loop. The loop really won't take that long, but, if for some reason your detest loops and you must have a one liner, then batch is the way to go.

I didn't test it but create a text file in the directory, call it `whatever.bat`, right click the file and select edit (or edit with notepad++). Then insert the following code:

```
set /a counter = 0
for /f %%f in (*.pdf) do set /a count += 1

echo counter: %counter%
pause
```

Save the file, and then double-click to open and run the program.